# How do I make Evolution check and notify new emails, without keeping main UI open?  

Tags: notification, email, evolution

How do I make Evolution keep checking my emails and notifying in the indicator applet without keeping the main UI open?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: I'm looking for something like this in the unity interface. I can't use Thunderbird because all my email history is in Evolution

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know this is not possible at the moment. There is already a bug report at launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-indicator/+bug/508608

Answer (score 3):

You could try installing 'mail-notification-evolution', its supposed to provide support for Mail Notification. I had some problems using it, but some people have had better luck than me.

```
sudo apt-get install mail-notification-evolution
```

Comment: I'm thinking more of something that integrates with the notification system in Ubuntu, and not a separate icon. So the envelope should turn green and upon clicking show the count against the mail accounts configured - just like it works when evolution window is open.

I'm guessing it is probably a feature which is just not present, in that case I might just file a feature request on Launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install alltray
```

Then start Evolution from AllTray. That'll give Evolution the ability to hide in the Notification Area.

Answer (score 0):

Use this program, it integrates with current ubuntu notification (envelope becomes green when new mail arrives):
https://launchpad.net/cloudsn